# Funny edit by community

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing, best-practices, community-user

Regarding [this review/edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/637610).

When I approved this edit, I didn't notice the text "anonymous user" and for some reason thought I was approving the OP's edit. Then I see the edit as done by "community".

Certainly now after reading the edit a second time, it seems like it keeps with the main theme of the original post while eliminating what sounds like anger but introducing still some odd language.

Is this acceptable? Should the edit be rolled back?

I just read about how community and anonymous editing operates, so I think I understand that. I'm asking about opinions on this specific instance in order to guide my future reviewing/editing.

Comment: The edit should not have been approved - it changes the meaning of the post substantially. That being said, I don't think this is actually a good answer, before *or* after the edit; it's mostly just opinion-based polemic.

Comment: It's plausible it actually was OP that made the edit to tone it down a bit. Hard to be sure though. Now that it is approved, I'd leave it as is. I disagree with @T.Bongers that it changes the meaning substantially. If OP has an issue with the edit *they* can roll it back.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Now that I understand that anonymous edits are possible, I'll be more careful. It didn't change what I perceived as the "core point" of the post: "math historians should step aside and listen to mathematicians". At first, I thought it was just spam or maybe one of those editing "tests", but the changes seemed reasonable, especially if it was the OP but just not logged in.

Comment: An important feature of the previous version is that the OP objects, on a matter of principle, to being the subject of a study by others, in the present case, historians. Since the edit erases this stance, I definitely find it unfortunate.

Comment: That phrase doesnt even say the same thing. Its completely different!